# Abrir aplicaçao do android studio no phonegap?t

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache-cordova

Eu desenvolvi um aplicativo no Android Studio e gostaria de exporta-lo para o phonegap a fim de poder utiliza-lo para multiplataformas. Como posso aproveitar o meu projeto no android studio no phonegap ja que ambos utilizam java?

Comment: A menos que eu esteja muito enganado, o PhoneGap utiliza javascript e a engine do Apache Cordova para gerar apps multi plataforma. Já o Android Studio é apenas a IDE que gera apps Android na sua linguagem nativa e, portanto, um projeto não é portável entre os dois

Comment: Entendido Caputo, obgdo.